# apache2 reverse proxy, how to serve multiple domains with backend recognizing only 1 valid uri

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy, rewrite, apache2

I have an Apache reverse proxy set up and my backend service is configured on a specific static `ServiceUri="site.com"`. I would like requests coming for multiple domains `a.site.com/data`, `b.site.com/data` etc. to be forwarded to my backend service. The problem is that my service does not recognize `a.site.com/data` as valid. Only `site.com/data` is served. I cannot change the backend to be flexible enough to accept `$random$.site.com` URIs. Is there a way for me to manipulate the request header within the VirtualHost so that my backend only sees a request of `site.com/data` but the reply to the queried clients still respects the original header? My VH looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        Listen 3000
        <VirtualHost _default_:3000>

                DocumentRoot /var/www/html

                SSLEngine on

                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/dom.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/dom.key

               <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>

                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>


               SSLProxyEngine on
               SSLProxyVerify none
               SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
               ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:9000/
               ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:9000/

        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache proxy\_http redirect to ip and set hostname](https://serverfault.com/questions/557233/apache-proxy-http-redirect-to-ip-and-set-hostname)

Comment: yes, it did! thank you